# Executing php script in terminal will not work on OSX but works in Linux

Tags: php, linux, macos, shell, exec

I have a script that uses php exec() function to run a command. It works fine in linux but not in OSX

The scripts are massive so i'm only showing relevant code:

sim.php:

```
$rootDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$simulation_id = mysql_insert_id();

exec("cd $rootDir; nohup php run_simulation.php $simulation_id 2> /tmp/errorphp.txt");
```

run_simulation.php

```
include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/include.php");
$simulation_id = $argv[1];

$get_simulation_row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select * from `_simulations` where `id` = $simulation_id"));

..... rest of code
```

this works fine on linux. However when its on OSX the script stops execution at include.

I know this because if i error log before the include the string is outputted to '/tmp/errorphp.txt' if i error log after the include the string is not outputted.

run_simulation.php

```
error_log('This string shows in log file');
$simulation_id = $argv[1];
error_log('so does this');

include(dirname(__FILE__) . "/include.php");

error_log('This and anything after does not show in log file');
```

Note: I know i should use PDO instead of mysql() But this is not my code i am editing it for someone. i will be chaining to PDO for them in the future

**Update**

include.php for chris

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
if (!$link) {
    die('DB error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('rates');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$currentLine;
$testLine;
$patternAr = array();
$performanceAr = array();
$pointsToLookAt = 30;
$forwardPoints = 10;
$patForRec = array();

function avgRange($range) {
    if (count($range) == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    $close = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($range); $i++) {
        $close += $range[$i]["close"];
    }
    $close = $close/count($range);
    return $close;
}

function highRange($range) {
    $high = -100000000;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($range); $i++) {
        $close = $range[$i]["close"];
        if ($close > $high) $high = $close;
    }
    return $high;
}

function lowRange($range) {
    $low = 100000000;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($range); $i++) {
        $close = $range[$i]["close"];
        if ($close < $low) $low = $close;
    }
    return $low;
}


function storePatterns($model_id, $exclude_hours = array()) {
    $time_start = microtime(true); 

    global $currentLine;
    global $patternAr;
    global $performanceAr;
    global $pointsToLookAt;
    global $forwardPoints;

    $x = count($currentLine) - ($pointsToLookAt*2);
    $y = $pointsToLookAt + 1;

    while ($y < $x) {

        // to exclude hours
        if (count($exclude_hours) > 0) {
            $c_date = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d H:i:s", $currentLine[$y]["date"]);
            $c_date = date_format($c_date, "H");

            if (in_array($c_date, $exclude_hours)) {
                echo "Excluding hour: $c_date \n";
                $y++;
                continue;
            }
        }

        $pattern = array();
        for ($i = $pointsToLookAt-1; $i >=0; $i--) {
            array_push($pattern, percentChange(avgLine($y-$pointsToLookAt), avgLine($y-$i)));
        }
        $outcomeRange = array_slice($currentLine, $y+1, $forwardPoints);
        $currentPoint = avgLine($y);
        $avgOutcome = avgRange($outcomeRange);
        $highOutcome = percentChange($currentPoint, highRange($outcomeRange));
        $lowOutcome = percentChange($currentPoint, lowRange($outcomeRange));
        $futureOutcome = percentChange($currentPoint, $avgOutcome);

        $outcomes = array(
            "high" => $highOutcome,
            "low" => $lowOutcome,
            "avg" => $futureOutcome
        );

        array_push($patternAr, $pattern);
        array_push($performanceAr, $outcomes);

        $y++;

        $currTime = microtime(true);
        $time_in = ($currTime - $time_start);
        //if ($time_in % 10 == 0) {
            //if (round(($y/($x-1))*100) != 0) {
            if ($y%100 == 0) {
                echo "Pattern progress: ".round(($y/($x-1))*100, 2)."%\n";

                updateModelProgress($model_id, round(($y/($x-1))*100, 2)."%");
            }
            //}
        //}
    }
    updateModelProgress($model_id, "100%");

    $models_file = array("patterns" => $patternAr, "outcomes" => $performanceAr);
    $models_file = json_encode($models_file);
    file_put_contents("models/$model_id".".model", $models_file);

    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $execution_time = ($time_end - $time_start)/60;

    //echo "Execution time $execution_time mins\n";
}

function updateModelProgress($model_id, $progress) {
    mysql_query("update `_models` set `progress` = '$progress' where `id` = $model_id");
}

function updateModelStatus($model_id, $status) {
    mysql_query("update `_models` set `status` = '$status' where `id` = $model_id");
}


function updateSimulationProgress($simulation_id, $progress) {
    mysql_query("update `_simulations` set `progress` = '$progress' where `id` = $simulation_id");
}

function updateSimulationStatus($simulation_id, $status) {
    mysql_query("update `_simulations` set `status` = '$status' where `id` = $simulation_id");
}

function updateSimulationDescription($simulation_id, $desc) {
    mysql_query("update `_simulations` set `description` = '$desc' where `id` = $simulation_id");
}

function currentPattern($upto) {
    global $patForRec;
    global $pointsToLookAt;
    global $testLine;
    $patForRec = array();

    $line_upto = array_slice($testLine, 0, $upto);

    for ($i = $pointsToLookAt; $i > 0; $i--) {
        array_push($patForRec, percentChange(avgTestLine(-$pointsToLookAt-1, $line_upto), avgTestLine(-$i, $line_upto)));
    }
}

function patternRecognition($upto, $minSimilarity) {
    global $patternAr;
    global $pointsToLookAt;
    global $patForRec;
    global $forwardPoints;
    global $testLine;
    global $performanceAr;
    $predictedOutcomesAr = array();
    $patFound = 0;
    $plotPatAr = array();
    $plotPatIndex = array();
    $p = 0;
    foreach ($patternAr as $pattern) {
        $simAr = array();
        $sim_bool = true;
        for ($i =0; $i < $pointsToLookAt; $i++) {
            $sim_num = 100.0-abs(percentChange($pattern[$pointsToLookAt-$i-1], $patForRec[$pointsToLookAt-$i-1]));
            if ($sim_num < 0) {
                $sim_bool = false;
                break;
            }
            array_push($simAr, $sim_num);

        }
        if ($sim_bool) {
            $howSim = array_sum($simAr)/count($simAr);

            if ($howSim > $minSimilarity) {
                array_push($plotPatAr, $pattern);
                array_push($plotPatIndex, $p);
                $patFound = 1;
            }
        }
        $p++;
    }
    $predArray = array();

    $returnArray = array();
    $returnArray["prediction"] = "none";


    if ($patFound == 1) {
        $p = 0;
        foreach ($plotPatAr as $pattern) {
            $futurePoints = $plotPatIndex[$p];

        //  print_r($performanceAr[$futurePoints]);
        //  print_r($patForRec[$pointsToLookAt-1]);

//          if ($performanceAr[$futurePoints]["avg"] > $patForRec[$pointsToLookAt-1]) {
            if ($performanceAr[$futurePoints]["avg"] > $pattern[$pointsToLookAt-1]) {
                array_push($predArray, 1.0);
            } else {
                array_push($predArray, -1.0);
            }
            array_push($predictedOutcomesAr, $performanceAr[$futurePoints]);
            $p++;
        }

        $realOutcomeRange = array_slice($testLine, $upto, $forwardPoints);
        $realOutcomeAvg = avgRange($realOutcomeRange);
        $realMovement = percentChange($testLine[$upto]["close"], $realOutcomeAvg);
        $predictedAvgOutcome = array_sum($predictedOutcomesAr)/count($predictedOutcomesAr);

        if (count($predArray) > 0) {
        //  print_r($predArray);
        }

        $predictionAvg = array_sum($predArray)/count($predArray);
        if ($predictionAvg < 0) {
//          echo "";
            $returnArray["prediction"] = "sell";
            $returnArray["pAvg"] = $predictionAvg;
        } 
        if ($predictionAvg > 0) {
            $returnArray["prediction"] = "buy";
            $returnArray["pAvg"] = $predictionAvg;
        }
    }
    $returnArray["patterns"] = $plotPatAr;
    $returnArray["original"] = $patForRec;
    $returnArray["outcomes"] = $predictedOutcomesAr;
    return $returnArray;
}

function percentChange($startPoint, $currentPoint) {
    $currentPoint = $currentPoint*1.0;
    try {
        $x = (($currentPoint-$startPoint)/abs($startPoint))*100.0;
        if ($x == 0) {
            return 0.0000000001;
        } else {
            return $x;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return 0.0000000001;
    }

}

function avgLine($row) {
    global $currentLine;
    if ($row < 0) {
        $row = count($currentLine)+$row;
    }
    return $currentLine[$row]["close"];
}

function avgTestLine($row, $line) {
    if ($row < 0) {
        $row = count($line)+$row;
    }

    return $line[$row]["close"];
}

function getRowsFromDatabase($query) {
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        array_push($array, $row);
    }
    return $array;
}

function getData($instrument, $from, $to, $interval='m') {
    global $currentLine;
    $groupby = "YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`), DAY(`date`), HOUR(`date`), MINUTE(`date`)";
    $interval = strtolower($interval);
    if ($interval == 'm' || $interval == 'minute' || $interval == 'minutes') {
        $groupby = "YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`), DAY(`date`), HOUR(`date`), MINUTE(`date`)";
    } else if ($interval == 'h' || $interval == 'hour' || $interval == 'hours') {
        $groupby = "YEAR(`date`), MONTH(`date`), DAY(`date`), HOUR(`date`)";
    }

    $instrument = strtoupper($instrument);
    $instrument = str_replace("/", "", $instrument);
    $query = mysql_query("select date, TRUNCATE(MAX((buy+sell)/2), 5) as high, TRUNCATE(MIN((buy+sell)/2), 5) as low, MIN(id) as open, MAX(id) as close, MAX(id) as close_id from `$instrument` where `date` > '$from' and `date` < '$to' group by $groupby order by `date`");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $open_row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select TRUNCATE(((buy+sell)/2), 5) as open from `$instrument` where `id` = ".$row["open"]));
        $close_row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select TRUNCATE(((buy+sell)/2), 5) as close from `$instrument` where `id` = ".$row["close"]));
        $row["open"] = $open_row["open"];
        $row["close"] = $close_row["close"];
        array_push($array, $row);
    }

    $rows = $array;
    return $rows;
}

function getTick($instrument, $tick_id) {
    $instrument = strtoupper($instrument);
    $instrument = str_replace("/", "", $instrument);
    $query = mysql_query("select * from `$instrument` where `id` = $tick_id");
    return mysql_fetch_array($query);
}




//print_r($performanceAr);
//print_r($patternAr);


//print_r($currentLine);

?>
```

Comment: This means it's throwing an error in `include.php`. Maybe find out what that error is and that will help with debugging.

Comment: I have tried to find the error in include.php but im not sure how to when executing through terminal. errors do not appear in the apache php error log. I do have a feeling its a mysql error though.

Comment: Add `echo dirname(__FILE__) . "/include.php";` right before the include to see if the path is what you think it is, and then check to see if the file exists on that path.

Comment: Errors wouldn't appear in the Apache error log if you are executing through the terminal. I don't really see how you can expect anyone to debug a file you haven't shown the contents of though.

Comment: Already tried that mate and it is the correct path. I could solve it easy if i could see the errors happening but i don't know how i can see them when running the script via terminal

Comment: Im aware they wouldn't show in apache logs because the script isn't running through apache. What file would you like to see the contents of? i will gladly update the question.

Comment: Well, `include.php` seems like a sensible file to provide since that is where the error is occurring.

Comment: I have added include.php for you. But please realise there is no error in the code, as i said all of these scripts work perfectly fine on linux. the issue is moving to OSX